# Why Random loss symbol does not work well

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, signal-processing, channel

I try to make random loss from a given bit stream. Assume that I have a bit stream as

```
10 01 10 11 00
```

Now I will create a code to implement random loss. The function with two inputs are original bit stream and percent loss. Output function is output bit stream

```
int* bitloss(int* orbit,int size_orbit,float loss_percent)
{
srand(time(NULL));
int* out_bitstream=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_orbit);
double randval ;
for(int i=0;i<size_orbit,i++)
{
    randval = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    if(randval<loss_percent) 
         out_bitstream[i]=-1;
     else out_bitstream[i]=orbit[i];

}
return out_bitstream;
}
```

This code will change value of original bit to -1 if the random belows than loss_percent.I call -1 bit is loss bit. So given loss_percent equals 20%. That mean I will loss 2 packets from 10 original bits. But when I do it. I show that some time I loss 0 bit, some time 4 bit, and sometime 2 bit. It is not stable. How to edit my code to stable loss. For example, I want to loss 20%. So the number of -1 bits are 2. Thank you so much

Comment: Where do you allocate `int* out_bitstream;`??

Comment: Sorry. It missed the line. But problem is not there. My problem is why random probability is not well

Comment: How did you `seed()` the random generator?

Comment: [Stop using `rand()`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming each bit has a probability `p` of being lost, and that bit loss are independent (this may not be the case in for example some fading channels where bit loss are more likely to occur in bursts), the number of bit lost in `N` bits follows a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Thus, for 10 bits and a loss rate of 20%, you would get the following distribution:
[image: B(10,0.2)]

Similarly, for 1000 bits and the same loss rate of 20%, you would get the following distribution:
[image: B(1000,0.2)]

Note that as the total number of bits gets larger, the binomial distribution approaches a Gaussian distribution with average `Np` and variance `Np(1-p)` .
Specifically, for the case of `N=1000` and `p=0.2` overlapping the Gaussian distribution over the binomial distribution gives:
[image]

As you can see it is a pretty good approximation.

Comment: Your first graph is interesting : Probability of 3 losses is noticeable less than prob. of 1 loss. My intuition said it would be symmetric around 2. And, my results in code in my answer back up your graph...?

Comment: The binomial distribution is symmetric if `p=0.5`. Otherwise it gets asymptotically symmetric as `N` increases.

Comment: @SleuthEye: THank you so much. Please guide me how to implement it by C/C++

Comment: The implementation you provided is typical of Monte-Carlo simulations, and would converge to the theoretical results shown here (taking the average over many frames). For reproducible results, make sure you control your seed (ie. not time). Otherwise, if you _must_ use a deterministic approach, `boost::math::binomial dist(N,p); for (i=0;i<N;i++) freq[i] = boost::math::pdf(dist, i);` would generate the distributions shown in the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with random numbers : They're random. If it always dropped 2 packets it wouldn't be random.

If you want to *always* lose 2 packets out of 10, then just randomly pick those packets. Something like...

```
int firstLoss, secondloss;
firstLoss = rand() % 10;

do {
  secondloss = rand() % 10;
} while (secondLoss == firstLoss);
```

We need the while loop (or a similar kind of 'tweak') to avoid selecting the same packet twice...

Comment: Thank you. How about loss around 2. Example 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @user3677103 : With what frequency distribution? You could first select how many packets to lose `(rand() % 3) +1` and then pick which those packets are. Either way, this isn't really random. The real problem is that 10 packets is not enough. The more you increase the sample size, the more the 'observed' loss will approach 20%.

Comment: It is good idea. How about your distribution? Because I don't know which is popular in channel conditions. Gaussian is more popular,right?

Comment: And I try to increase packet size to 1000. But with 20% loss rate. The loss packet will from 0 to 400 packets are loss. Do you have code to adjust it

Comment: Look at this snippet which uses your technique, but just counts and plots the frequency of each # of dropped values. You'll see it is already a normal distribution. http://ideone.com/OigeZf