# How to make random loss bits follow Gaussian distribution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, signal-processing

Currently, I am making a program to generate loss bit with given loss rate.

Assume that I have number of bit input N=1000 where the number of bit lost in `N` bits follows a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Assuming each bit has a probability p=20% of being lost, and that bit loss are independent. Thus, for 1000 bits and a loss rate of 20%, you would get the following gaussian distribution:[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079138/why-random-loss-symbol-does-not-work-well) with mean is Np and variance is Np(1-p). We can implement it by using Monte-Carlo simulations. It is my knowledge that I get at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079138/why-random-loss-symbol-does-not-work-well).

I don't know how to implement that scheme in C/C++. Could you suggest to me how to generate bit error with input are total bits and probability error. This is my attempt in C/C++ but it did not look like the theory:

```
int* bitloss(int* orbit,int size_orbit,int loss_percent) {

    int* out_bitstream=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size_orbit);
    int randval ;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    generator.seed( rd() );
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, 100);

    for(int i=0;i<size_orbit,i++) {
        rand_loss = distribution(generator);
        if(randval<((int)lossbitprob*100)) 
             out_bitstream[i]=-1;
        else out_bitstream[i]=orbit[i];
    }

    return out_bitstream;
}
```

Comment: If you really require `that bit loss are independent` then you require a uniform distribution of random numbers.  The resulting number of bits actually lost per orbit will tend to approach the normal distribution.

Comment: @quamrana: Really. We can use uniform distribution for random number,right? So my code is updated. Could you check help me?

Comment: Yes, your code now uses a uniform distribution for the random numbers. You still need to sort out other problems in your code above - you should really submit code that actually compiles!

Comment: @quamrana: Thank you. I am running the program to check output is close to gaussian disstribution or not. Let waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the number of samples (size_orbit) is large enough, the code of the [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079138/why-random-loss-symbol-does-not-work-well):

```
for(int i=0;i<size_orbit,i++)
{
  randval = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
  if(randval<loss_percent) 
     out_bitstream[i]=-1;
  else out_bitstream[i]=orbit[i];
}
```

Should (without changes) converge to the stated theoretical result.
That is, if you were to compute an histogram using:

```
int histogram[size_orbit+1] = {0};
for (int j=0; j<number_of_experiments; j++)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<size_orbit; i++)
  {
    if (out_bitstream[i] == -1)
      count++;
  }
  histogram[count]++;
}
```

Then the relative occurrence of total number of bit loss in each experiment should converge to Gaussian distribution with mean of Np and variance of Np(1-p). Or in other words, the number of loss bits in each experiment might appear "as-if" generated by a process such as:

```
double mean        = size_orbit * loss_percent; // Np
double variance    = size_orbit * loss_percent * (1.0 - loss_percent); // Np(1-p)
double sigmarandom = sqrt(std::max(0.0, variance));
std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(mean,sigmarandom);
int lossbitcount = round(distribution(generator));
```

Comment: Thank sir, But i suggest using  std::uniform_int_distribution<> instead of randval = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; I am running the program to check the result.

Comment: @SleuthEye: Please note that the OP has now edited the code in the question.  However, you still have a correct answer.

Comment: @SleuthEye and quamrana: I checked the result. the loss count does not look like gaussian disstribution. You can check it at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6f6af09b3cb2fe12

Comment: set `loss_count=0` before `for (int n=0...`, then increment hist only _after_ `for` loop.

Comment: @SleuthEye: Let check result at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=02e477391a8ee1f3 . The loss count looks like uniform distribution.

Comment: move `++hist[loss_count];` after the `for (int n=0...` loop (ie. increment only once per experiment). Look at my implementation for reference.

Comment: This is final result. Thank sir http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=45e4ca09d53c747c